# how to convert raw data to int32 in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-conversion

I get this `data =  [0, 4, -109, -31]` from modbus and I know this `data = 300001` but I don't know how to convert it properly to get to that `300001`.
I've tried lots of methods found online but I haven't got it to work.
Thank you for any help

Edit:
As I understand `0` needs to be shifted by `24`, `4` shifted by `16`, `-109 (256-109 = 147)` so it would be `147` and needs to be shifted by `8` and the last one `-31 (256-31 = 225)` we take as is.
So quick recap `data = [0, 4, 147, 225]` and `0 * 2^24 + 4 * 2^16 + 147 * 2^8 + 225 = 300001`
Now this needs to be codified.
Are there any proper ways to do it in js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a data view with a buffer and set the bytes

```js
var data = [0, 4, -109, -31]

// Create a data view of a buffer
var view = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(4));

// set bytes
data.forEach((v, i) => view.setInt8(i, v));

var num = view.getInt32(0);
console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can bitshift and sum your numbers:

```
data =  [0, 4, -109, -31]

console.log( data[0] << 24 | data[1] << 16 | data[2] << 8 | data[3] );
```

Comment: You can use `|` instead of `+` for clarity. After all, the bytes should occupy mutually exclusive bits in the 32-bit integer.